# Error regarding query work item gate in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

thanks in advance.
I am facing an issue while adding gate (query work item) to control the azure pipeline flow.

Error message i am getting from logs :)

```
============================================================================== 
Task         : Query Work Items
Description  : Execute a work item query and check the number of items returned
Version      : 0.0.16
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help URL     : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/work-item-query
============================================================================== 

                Response Code: 0
                Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: {"$id":"*","innerException":null,"message":"TF*****: The query 1****-****-****-****-******* does not exist, or you do not have permission to read it.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.QueryItems.QueryItemNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"QueryItemNotFoundException","errorCode":****,"eventId":****}
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (type WebException)
                Evaluation of expression 'xor(and(or(eq(root['queryType'], 'oneHop'), eq(root['queryType'], 'tree')), and(le(count(root['workItemRelations']), 5), ge(count(root['workItemRelations']), 0))), and(eq(root['queryType'], 'flat'), and(le(count(root['workItems']), 5), ge(count(root['workItems']), 0))))' failed.
                
Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object. (type DistributedTaskException)
```

What I have tried already :)

1. I have added user to all the groups like , build administrator, contributer , project administrators.
2. Already tried updating query permission, but no luck.

I am unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the account `{project name} Build Service ({Org name})` does not have enough permission to access the query.

Steps:

Open **Queries**->select `...` on your query and add that account `{project name} Build Service ({Org name})` with READ access.

Note: We should provide the permission for the account `{project name} Build Service ({Org name})` to read under **Shared Queries** page and select query permission page.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When granting permission, search for the project name, as it does not appear in the initial list, only after performing the search. The project will only appear in the list after you perform the search.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYlLc.png)